# Getting error message while opening eclipse,see the log file error message showing

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu-18.04

I have Ubuntu 18.04 and I installed java and other files but when open eclipse then it showing error message.

[image: log file error message]

I tried below command

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure eclipse-pde eclipse-jdt
```

but its not working in my case.

and log file data is :-

> !SESSION Thu Mar 28 10:30:56 IST 2019 ------------------------------------------
>   !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2019-03-28 10:30:56.050
>   !MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
>   !STACK
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStart$
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>           at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:626)
>           at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
>           at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
>           at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)

Comment: may be you can try below one https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/359458/

Comment: Well what does it say in the log file? Without the details from the log we can't help.

Comment: @greg-449 I am updating question.

Comment: What version of Eclipse and what version of Java? It looks like you are probably using an old version of Eclipse which doesn't understand a more modern Java.

Comment: @greg-449 my eclipse version is "Photon Release (4.8.0)" and java version is 1.8.0_201